# Is there a way to have all subclasses of a specific class execute a function whenever an attribute is accessed?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class with a custom `__getattribute__` definition, for example:

```
class DummyBaseClass:
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        #Interesting logging/validation code here
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

I would like subclasses of this class to also execute what is in the `#Interesting code` block when they have their attributes accessed, without explicitly adding a `__getattribute__` definition to every subclass.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
class DummyBaseClass:
    test = 'Hello World'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        #Interesting logging/validation code here
        print(f"{self}: __getattribute__ is called")
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


class DummySubClass(DummyBaseClass):
    pass


class AnotherDummySubClass(DummyBaseClass):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('Hi, I do more than the others when __getattribute__ gets called')
        return super().__getattribute__(name)


class JustAnotherDummySubClass(AnotherDummySubClass):
    test_german = 'Hallo Welt'


print(DummyBaseClass().test)
print(DummySubClass().test)
print(AnotherDummySubClass().test)
print(JustAnotherDummySubClass().test_german)
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the `#Interesting logging/validation code` called without having to explicitly define `__getattribute__` in every subclass.

Comment: It's what `DummySubClass` does, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, testing in an online interpret it does appear to work.  Will need to figure out why it doesn't appear to work in my environment.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot: You cannot execute e.g. `self.do_stuff()` inside `__getattribute__` without an external condition because this would call __getattribute__ again and lead to infinite recursion. For that case I suggest using a classmethod or staticmethod instead of `self.do_stuff()`